# How to generate boot failure?

Tags: boot

I am testing dual-boot system and want to generate a boot failure when boot into one of the systems (both are Linux), basically to test grub-reboot function. My question is how to easily modify some files to cause boot failure (should be easily recoverable)? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg and comment out the `initrd` line from the entry you want to fail.  Without the initrd the kernel will panic trying to locate the rootfs by uuid.